# React's exhaustive-deps linter rule triggered in one case but not the other?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'd like to adapt this Code Sandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/lx947qjv0z, to my own React app. I've tried to simply `useGoogleMap.js`,

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import GoogleMapsApiLoader from "google-maps-api-loader";

const apiKey = "AIzaSyCVBthtEmWi0Ul8mejDQrBlOULXB1kTB3I";

const eventsMapping = {
  onCenterChanged: ["center_changed", map => map.getCenter()],
  onBoundsChanged: ["bounds_changed", map => map.getBounds()]
};

export default function useGoogleMap({ zoom, center, events }) {
  const [mapState, setMapState] = useState({ loading: true });
  const mapRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    GoogleMapsApiLoader({ apiKey }).then(google => {
      const map = new google.maps.Map(mapRef.current, { zoom, center });
      Object.keys(events).forEach(eventName =>
        map.addListener(eventsMapping[eventName][0], () =>
          events[eventName](eventsMapping[eventName][1](map))
        )
      );

      setMapState({ maps: google.maps, map, loading: false });
    });
  }, []);
  return { mapRef, ...mapState };
}
```

to the following (since I don't believe I need the `events`):

```
import {useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import GoogleMapsApiLoader from 'google-maps-api-loader';

const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY;

export default function useGoogleMap(options) {
  const [mapState, setMapState] = useState();
  const mapRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    GoogleMapsApiLoader({ apiKey }).then(google => {
      const map = new google.maps.Map(mapRef.current, options);
      setMapState({ maps: google.maps, map });
    });
  }, [options]);
  return { mapRef, ...mapState };
}
```

In my own code, if I omit `options` from the dependency array passed as the second argument to `useEffect()`, I get a linter warning:

> React Hook has a missing dependency: 'options'

[image]

What perplexes me is: why does the original Sandbox code not have such a warning? Aren't `zoom` and `center` also dependencies of its effect in `useEffect()`?

Comment: Just to check if both the apps have same eslint-setup, could you verify once if copying the source code as it is (with `zoom` and `center`) also added the deps (`[zoom, center]`) to your effect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That codesandbox you post is also receiving the error
[image]

This article may help https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies

essentially what is happening is that useEffect doesn't have immediate access to options. So you need to pass options as a parameter to useEffect like so....

```
export default function useGoogleMap(options) {
  const [mapState, setMapState] = useState({ loading: true });
  const mapRef = useRef();

  useEffect((options) => {

    GoogleMapsApiLoader({ apiKey }).then(google => {
      const map = new google.maps.Map(mapRef.current, options);

      setMapState({ maps: google.maps, map, loading: false });
    });
  }, []);
  return { mapRef, ...mapState };
}
```

That will get rid of your error!

Comment: Hope that helps!